# Numerical Analysis Double Precision

Tags: numerical-methods, number-systems

I have a very simple question about double precision.

Assume that $x=10^{20}+300$.

What is the double precision representation of $x$?

Now the answer is $10^{20}$. What I don't understand is,why?

After all,the largest number when using *DP* is about $10^{307}$, so why do we lose that $300$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In double precision, the next representable number after $10^{20}$ is $10^{20} (1+\varepsilon)$, for $\varepsilon =  2^{-52} \approx 2.2204 \cdot 10^{-16}$. Now
$$
10^{20} (1+\varepsilon) > 10^{20} + 2 \cdot 10^{4} = 10^{20} +20000 > 10^{20} + 300
$$
Therefore, $10^{20}+300$ is not representable. The closest representable number is $10^{20}$ and so $10^{20}+300=10^{20}$ in floating point.

Answer (score 0):

beacuse :

- in your number is 19 digits between 1 and 3
- double precision number has 15 -17 [significant decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

so 300 is lost due to [sum of  big and small number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)

Comment: What do you mean by "in your number is $19$ digits between $1$ and $3$"?

Comment: print your number ( sum) and number the digits starting from digit 1 thru zeros to digit 3